# How to save the id of an element in a state in react

Tags: reactjs

Good morning, I have a question for you. I am learning react and I have a question that I cannot solve.
I'm mapping a json and rendering the elements in an option inside a select. Every time the value of the select is changed I need to save the value and the id. I save the value by setting a state like event.target.value but I don't know how to save the id, I tried to do something similar as I did with the value but it didn't work.
I'm sorry if the question is basic, I wouldn't be finding answers, in advance, thank you very much

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
const [id, setId] = React.useState('');

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    setId(event.target.id)
};

<select id={id} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
     {hologram.map((option) => (
      <option id={option.id} value={option.path}>{option.denomination}</option>
     ))}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.target` to get the `element`

Then use `element.options.seletedIndex` to get the selected index.

To get the original option, use `element.options[element.options.seletedIndex]`, on this DOM element, you can find the `id` and `value`

---

Small demo:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
    const [id, setId] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        let element = event.target;
        let options = element.options;
        let { id, value } = options[options.selectedIndex];
 
        setValue(value);
        setId(id);
        
        console.log(`Change: ${value} (${id})`);
    };

    return (
        <select id={id} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
             <option id={1} value={'foo'}>{'Foo'}</option>
             <option id={2} value={'bar'}>{'Bar'}</option>
        </select>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```